# export to csv - set number cell format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export

I'm trying working on convert 2 headres from my csv file that I'm exporting 
to a "NUMBER" format (in the Excel spreedsheet) instead of the default type that it generate which is "GENERAL".
I've looked in couple of guides but nothing actually help.
My code is :
 {

```
  csv_data = ::CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv <<  ["phone number", "Name", "Email Adress"]

  @object.each do |obj|
    csv << [obj.phone_number, obj.name, obj.user_email ]
  end
```

}

thank you ahead !

Comment: CSV files do not contain type information - interpretation of the cell content is left to the parser/reader.

Comment: @eugen so what you say actually - is that I cant change the type?

Comment: @miss_M yes, you're not going to be able to define any type information because CSV doesn't support that. You'd have to look at exporting to a different spreadsheet format, possibly using something like https://github.com/randym/axlsx

Comment: @shadwell Do you now easy&fast way to convert CSV to XSLX in rails ?

Comment: @miss_M no, 'fraid not. I would have thought going straight to xslx would be preferable given your formatting requirements.